# When desiging the ER diagram for database?

Tags: database, database-design

When we say each department is managed by an employee , Does that imply that each department must be managed by an employee and hence a total participation constraint ?

Comment: this sounds like homework, could you provide a bit more of context to the question?

Comment: i mean what is there a difference of saying that each department must be managed by an employee , and that each department is managed by an employee ?  This is not homework , that's studying :D

Comment: Welcome to the wiki, attend on [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it seems none of your questions have got a check mark as the correct answer of the question!

Answer (score 0):

> Does that imply that each department must be managed by an employee
>   and hence a total participation constraint ?

Yes in other words it's a one to one relationship

Comment: The only correct part of your answer is the first word.  All the rest is an unwarranted conclusion, and thus wrong.  How did you get from "each department is managed by someone who is an employee" to "no employee can manage more than one department ?"

Answer (score 0):

In my observation (based on question body and comments):
The relation is **one-to-many**, showing that an employee can be the manager of many departments.
None of the predicates shows on-to-one relation, since there is no peripatetic saying that an employee can be manger of one department.

**The difference:** (it is opinion base to decide if there is any difference as comments of this answer shows)

> Each department **must** be managed by **an** employee

Emphasis a **mandatory one-to-many** relation (is-managed-by) 

[image]

> Each department is managed by an employee

Emphasis an **optional one-to-many** relation.
[image]

**Hint:** 

Documenting data integrity constraints is most widely done using natural language, which often produces a quick dive into ambiguity.
 If you use plain English to express
data integrity constraints, you’ll inevitably hit the problem of how the English sentence maps,
unambiguously, into the table structures.Different programmers (and users alike) will interpret such sentences differently, because they all try to convert these into something that will
map into the database design. Programmers then code their perception of the constraint (not
necessarily the specifier’s).
[A formal manner will be using the logic and set theory](http://books.google.com/books?id=2hM3-xxZC-8C&pg=PA140&lpg=PA140&dq=Documenting%20data%20integrity%20constraints%20is%20most%20widely%20done%20using%20natural%20language&source=bl&ots=VfQruEcZ6R&sig=lNSgRBo70PN6pfiVLpA1nK90Lls&hl=en&sa=X&ei=vS-oUouAL8THsga74IDQBw&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=Documenting%20data%20integrity%20constraints%20is%20most%20widely%20done%20using%20natural%20language&f=false).

Comment: "Each department _IS_ managed by an employee" is quite unambiguous even in natural language.  It is quite indubitable that there cannot be any departments that are not managed by any employee.  How you can possibly conclude from the given sentence that the relationship can be optional is beyond me.  In this particular case, there is NO difference.

Comment: In my observation the only difference is in 'MUST' keyword mentioned on comments of @Aboria, that would lead me to mandatory and optional relegation. The debate proves the Hint

Comment: In your "optional" model, take any department that does not have a manager.  Does that department satisfy the stated requirement "each department is managed by an employee" ?

Comment: What is the difference between : 'each department is managed by an employee' and 'Each department must be managed by an employee' ? So the answer of your question is Yes with an optional FK.

Comment: Saying that each department is managed by an employee is logically equivalent to saying that there cannot exist a department that is not managed by an employee.  That book you pointed to with its "formal manners" has all the material necessary to understand (and prove) that.  And to understand that if you design your database with an "optional" FK, then your design does not accurately (and in full) represent the business scenario at hand.

Comment: So in your opinion : 'each department is managed by an employee' <=>   'Each department must be managed by an employee' ???

Comment: Of course.  If you want to demonstrate the opposite, you'll have to come up with an example of a department that is not managed by an employee but still doesn't falsify the predicate "each department is managed by an employee".  Good luck with that.

Comment: Assuming the mandatory relationship, lets start saving our first records of employee and department to the tables, which one will be the first record? employee needs a department and department needs a manager! the mandatory FK in both sides will be a cyclic dependency. it is a misleading so the assumption is wrong.

Comment: You are conflating the conceptual level with the implementation level.  Conceptual models do not serve the purpose of telling us which "things to store first".  And even if they did, what you believe to be a problem here really isn't.  SQL has deferred constraint checking for this scenario, and true relational systems per The Third Manifesto have multiple assignment for this.  In SQL : I store any one of the two, I store the other one of the two, then I make the system check the constraints.  In D : I store the two in a single go, systems checks constraints after that.